# PayPal - OAuth2 API Access?

Tags: paypal

I have a big question:

First time we create an Application, Okay - Thats cool. Then we use the client_id and the secret key for authentication... OK, its done - Works fine for the Sandbox.

**But yet I have a problem to set it public:**

How I can create an application (to become the client_id and the secret key) for production websites?
On my account I only have the "old data" when i go to My Profile > API Access.

Can anyone say, how I can use the PayPal OAuth2 without the sandbox?

Doc: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same application that you've created on developer.paypal.com, you will see both test and live credentials. If for any reason you need to be verified, it will show you a button to get started with the verification process, which will enable your live credentials.

Comment: Yeah, PayPal has hide that. Under the Sandbox data, is a little Link to get the live credentials, Thanks